# css min-height center column

Tags: css

I need help to fix the next layout, because:

- It doesnt look right for IE
- The footer doesnt stay at bottom when #columns content grows up
- I need to make the #column container 100% min-height with small content

Thanks in advance!

This is my code:

```
<style>
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 }

 body, html {
  background: silver;
  height: 100%;
 }

 #header {      
  min-width: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background: red;
 }

 #columns {
  width: 1000px;
  background: white; 
  margin: 0 auto;  
  padding-bottom: 40px; 
  border: 1px solid black;     
 }

 #footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  min-width: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background: black;
 }
```

```
<body>
  <div id="header"></div>
  <div id="columns"></div>
  <div id="footer"></div>  
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this (**edited**) : 
JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NeCc3/14/

```
 * {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 }

 body, html {
  background: silver;
  height:100%
 }

 #header {      
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background: red;
 }

 #columns{
  min-height:100%;
  width: 1000px;
  background: white; 
  margin: 0 auto;  
  padding-bottom: 40px; 
  border: 1px solid black;     
 }

 #footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background: black;
 }
```